# PHPExcel : STATEMENT_IF Formula not working return true

Tags: phpexcel

I'm trying to match if condition through phpexcel library but formula returns me every time true condition, here is my code

$condition = "B2-300=0"; // if enter 1 instead of zero then formula still return zero. I have 300 integer value in B2 cell.

echo $ajaxFinalValue = PHPExcel_Calculation_Logical::STATEMENT_IF($condition, $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('B6'), $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('C6'));
i
B6 value is answer but when i false the condition then also return B6

please advise what to do.

Thanks
Adil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The STATEMENT_IF() method expects the boolean **result** of a condition, not the condition itself.

If you want to evaluate the condition itself, then you need to call the calculation engine to handle the evaluation, not the functions that it calls:

There is a slight difference between PHPExcel version 1.7.9 and earlier versions

PHPExcel version 1.7.9

```
$ifFormula = '=IF(B2-300=0,B6,C6)';
$formulaResult = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance($objPHPExcel)
    ->calculateFormula(
        $ifFormula,
        'A1',
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')
    );
var_dump($formulaResult);
```

earlier versions

```
$ifFormula = '=IF(B2-300=0,B6,C6)';
$formulaResult = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()
    ->calculateFormula(
        $ifFormula,
        'A1',
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1')
    );
var_dump($formulaResult);
```

Comment: Hi again Mark Baker,

Your solution are really works for me but i have an issue in if statement formula in earlier version that when i enter text in true or false condition. then formula gives me ref# error. when enter cell cordinates then it runs fine. but i also want to add some text like, if condition true then "Hurray" not "better luck next time". how to do these things with above formula engines.

Thanks

Comment: It should work exactly as it would work in MS Excel itself: If the condition needs evaluating to determine if it's true or false, then you have to evaluate it through the calc engine using calculateFormula()

Comment: HI, 
Actually it is working like excel but i want something like that IF(A2-A1, "Yes Ok!","Wrong Case!") means i want text in true or false condition except. 
Thanks

Comment: Hi,
how can we just display the A,B,C,D column names through phpexcel. is there any function.
Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you mean: try using the Excel COLUMN() function - http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/column-function-HP010062409.aspx

Comment: actually i want all the column names from loaded excel sheet A, B, C, D, E, F and onward till end.

Comment: You can use `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn();` or `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn();` to return the highest column address used in a worksheet

Comment: i don't want the highest last column name i want all column names.

Comment: If you're using 26 or less columns, then use the getHighestColumn() function to get the character for the highest column; then use the PHP range() function... range('A',$resultOfGetHighestColumn);

Comment: Hi, 
Can we manage multiple sheet calculations with on formula like, 
i pick A2 value from sheet1 and i pick A3 value from sheet2 then how can i perform function and function picks first value from sheet 1 and 2nd value from sheet 2 or how to know that 1st is from sheet1 and 2nd value is from sheet 2 maybe we can enter first value from sheet 2 and 2nd value from sheet1 so is it possible in your PHPExcel Library. Thanks

Comment: You can, in the same way that MS Excel can.... express the formula exactly as you would in MS Excel, and see: but if you have more questions, please ask them as questions, not as comments against the answer to this question

Comment: Hi,
basically i cannot put more question on it . so i only ask question through comments to you sir. so in excel, excel takes sheet parameter but how i can give phpexcel library to give sheet parameter on the fly when user enter the value in it. how please

Comment: You should ask a new question - if it's something that could be useful to other stackoverflow users, they'll never see it if its just in the comments

Comment: `='Worksheet Name'!A2` is how you'd reference a cell in a different worksheet in an MS Excel formula, and the same should work in exactly the same way in PHPExcel

Comment: hi,
Thanks for your answer , bascially i'm banned for ask question on stackoverflow so that's why i cannot add question, this question was on so i only add comments it. other wise i must post question for this. Thanksk

Comment: hi,
can we add multiple excel files into memory and then get peform function on sheet basis. in php excel library. thanks

Comment: You can have multiple Excel files in memory (if you have enough memory) but you can't have a formula in one file that accesses the other; only between sheets in the same file

Comment: that good that we can have multiple files in memory but 1 file 1 sheet  1 cell like A1 , 2 file 1 sheet 1 cell liek A1 Can we perform functions like file1!sheet1!A1+file2!sheet1!A1 in your library.

Comment: No, the calculation engine doesn't support references between different files, even if they are both in memory at the same time

Comment: can you add this functionality please because my project is based on your library and 1 of these is requirement of my project or can you give suggestion what is the way to handle with without going into memory for calculation. thanks

Comment: I'm sorry - that functionality won't be added: it's problematic when the external sheet isn't available in memory (or can't be loaded into memory), and adds an enormous performance overhead that makes the library unworkable.

Comment: so any more idea to do that with php coding or your function engine can manipulate values instead of cell cordinates, my mean i will give them value to your excel fuction engine to perform is possible?
like this
  $conditions = "=(".$_POST['clickcell'].")";
            echo $ajaxFinalValue = PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance()->calculateFormula(
            $conditions, 'A1', $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('A1'));

Comment: Ok How to identify that the excel file is loaded in the memory. and then how to perform functions on it from another php file. because on it there is no loaded code added. can we do operations through variable object one time load excel file trhough load function and then use it and access it from another file and manipulate functions is it possible?

Comment: You'll need to rewrite a lot of the code: You'll need to flag up the file that was loaded in the PHPExcel object or to create a new PHPExcel_Collection class to hold that information; and you'll need to modify the calculation engine to work with that additional information rather than throw an exception when it encounters a file reference in a formula - be warned, it's not a few trivial code changes